# Why is my blueprint not visible as a render?

Tags: rendering, vertices

[image]

I created this blueprint using the vertices of a plane but the image is completely blank when I hit render

Comment: If there are no faces then there are no surfaces to render. For things like that you should use the grease pencil. Alternatively you could convert the mesh to curves and give them some bevel to make them "visible"

Comment: I converted them to curves and nothing changed.

Comment: did you give the curves any bevel?

Comment: yeah, but I think I'll just redo it with the grease pencil. do I have to be in the animation tab to be able to use it?

Comment: it doesn't help if you don't show the results of the options given to you... As for the grease pencil, there are plenty of videos out there that show you how to use it. The easiest way is using File>New>2D animation.

Comment: Note that you don't need to start over, you can also convert the object to grease pencil if you are using 2.9

Answer (score 2):

Edge lines between vertices don't have any volume, so they can't be seen. You can use a wireframe modifier to add thickness to the lines, also make sure you have some sort of light in the scene or it might be too dark to see.